# proyecto en React y NodeJS con excel

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, excel, backend

A un compañero a y mi que somos practicantes de Ingeniera en software nos pusieron el siguiente proyecto: nos dieron un libro de Excel, bueno ese libro de Excel hay que proyectarlo en un entorno web, con React y Node.JS, también hay tenemos que implementarlo en back-end.

Mi compañero y yo no sabemos cómo empezar ni cómo seguir desarrollándolo , algunas personas nos pueden ayudar explicándonos cómo se puede hacer, cómo empezar, cómo implantarlo a un entorno web utilizando React y NodeJS y cómo implantarlo a un back-end?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: Comiencen por lograr abrir el Excel e imprimir parte de éste en la consola usando nodejs.

Comment: Es probable que esta pregunta sea respondida con opiniones más que con hechos y citas. Debe ser actualizada para que conduzca a respuestas basadas en hechos.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con libros de excel, o mas bién, archivos de hojas de cálculo te recomiendo esta libreria.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

La forma en que lo hagan dependerá de sus necesidades, también es importante aprender a trabajar con buffers y archivos.

He armado un [ejemplo en codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/excel-reading-with-xlsx-krgzmr) para entenderlo bien, imprime en consola la primera hoja como un arreglo de objetos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, cualquier duda te pregunto.

Comment: @JuanPabloOssaArgáez Bueno, si te sirvió puedes marcar la respuesta como respuesta aceptada